# Import GeoTIFFs to QGIS via the API

Tags: pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity

I am trying to import GeoTIFFs to QGIS via the API, remove some colors and change the transparency.

Why is my transparency command ignored in the script below?

```
#Import TIF and set Transparency

My_tiff_1 = "C:/Users/Data/Cloud1.tif"

My_tiff_2 = "C:/Users/Data/Cloud2.tif"

#name layer
Name_of_layer = "A_Layer"

#set transparency as  percent

opacity = 0.5

def getTif(tiff, Name_of_layer, opacity):
   
    iface.addRasterLayer(tiff, Name_of_layer)

    layer=iface.activeLayer()
    layer.renderer().setOpacity(opacity)

    #colorize the layer

    renderer = layer.renderer()

    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    band = renderer.band()
    classes = renderer.classes()

    #remove first color in Palette

    del classes[0]
    del classes[0]

    renderer = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer(provider, band, classes)

    #Refresh the layer
    layer.setRenderer(renderer)

    layer.triggerRepaint()


getTif(My_tiff_1, Name_of_layer, opacity)
getTif(My_tiff_2, Name_of_layer, opacity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are juggling multiple renderer objects there.

`renderer = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer(provider, band, classes)` is the renderer that will be used to render your layer so if you want it to be transparent, call `setOpacity` on that object not the layer's existing renderer that is replaced by this one.

Comment: great, thanks!  I did this and it worked:   new_renderer = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer(provider, band, classes)
    new_renderer.setOpacity(opacity)